# Get widget settings function?

Tags: php, functions, widgets

I am using this to find if a new widget has been added or removed from my site:

```
serialize(retrieve_widgets());
```

Works great for added or removed widgets. But it doesn't detect if a widget setting has changed. Say I have a widget which lets me upload an image, and I replace the image in this widget. This change will not be seen with `retrieve_widgets()`

How do I detect change in all the widgets?